# Alternate for KILL command in linux

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system, kill-process

I have written a script file for stopping of process. But there is need to write script file without using `kill` cmd.
Is there any alternate cmd for `kill` cmd in Linux?

Comment: I worked with a guy who used the REBOOT button on a VAX 5500 multiuser system for that purpose. It made the rest of the users upset but got the job done.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you cannot use the `kill` command?

Comment: Actually my kill script is not killing instances on the cloud DB.So much instances created there and kill cmd is not killing the sessions.So i thought of something else to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at `pkill` command:

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pkill.htm